# Dedicate a node to a stream - Security rules

Tags: qliksense

Can anyone let me know how to show a stream only in a specific node

i have a 2 nodes cluster.. and i would like to dedicate RIM01 specific to Stream1. RIM02 to Steam2.  Meaning any request to that streams or apps in that stream should go to there nodes

So, if a go to RIM01 the Stream2 should be hidden etc...

1. Central node
2. RIM02 -- Repository + Engine
3. RIM03 -- Repository + Engine + Scheduler

i tried lot of security rules like

Filter : ServerNodeConfiguration_*,Stream_*

```
(node.@NodeUse="dev") and (node.@NodeType=stream.@StreamType and !resource.stream.Empty())
```

or

Filter : ServerNodeConfiguration_*,Stream_*

```
((resource.resourcetype = "Nodes" and resource.name="RIM01")) and ((resource.name="test"))
```

but none of them work :/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, at present, load balancing in Qlik Sense applies to Apps, not Streams. Load Balancing routes apps to servers, whereas security rules govern stream visibility. And, unfortunately, there is not a clean mechanism to use node meta-data in security rules. All in all, there isn't a solution for hiding a stream on a given server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was the same conclusion we had two months ago, it's not possible to hide a stream in a specific node

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, you can designate the apps are only readable on single node, so depending on how your user stream rights are configured some users may see an empty stream on the node where the app cannot be accessed.

There's some interesting stuff happening with the multi cloud capability where the concept of streams is now collections, which gives lots more flexibility around this type of thing. Alas QEFE capability is only just come with June 2018, and access is limited to certain use cases / customers.